# Percentage of Discount based on the Cart Subtotal?

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I have to apply 10% discount of subtotal in the cart page. In the backend configuration of the Magento, I could see the option of applying fixed amount discount for whole cart. But I need percentage of discount of the cart sub total. How to do it? Can I achieve it by backend configuration itself or it will need code rewriting?

Comment: Did you tried with `Percentage of Product Price discount` ? settings under `shopping cart price rule` , because this going to be work for subtotal.

Comment: Yes, that is accomplishing my needs. I found just now. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `Percentage of Product Price discount` , this option will apply for individual products and also to subtotal.

[image]